# Change style of a given day in ng-pick-datetime

Tags: angular, npm, datetimepicker

I'm using [Angular Date Time Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) in my frontend.

My method in the backend calculates all the unavailable dates for the user. I want to change color in the calendar on each of the days that the user is unavailable. Basically I want to find a way to style the component by changing color on the unavailable days.

I can't seem to find a way; can someone point me in the right direction? Or maybe even recommend another way to do this.

Comment: Please post some code that shows a bare minimum of what you've tried so far, or a minimum working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out the unavailable days, then this CSS should do the trick:

```
.owl-dt-calendar-cell-disabled {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

It basically sets the color of any disabled date to red.

Comment: Thank you sir, I managed to get it to work because of your tip :)! But what about styling the timepicker if the choosed time already got an event booked? Do you have any idea? If it's even possible?

Comment: @KENUBBE extra questions are best asked as their own standalone questions, as this will attract more folks who can offer a solution **and** help anyone looking for answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can change the color 
-----> src\styles.scss

for ex

```
.owl-dt-calendar-table .owl-dt-calendar-cell-in-range {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.owl-dt-container-info .owl-dt-container-info-active {
    color: red;
}

.owl-dt-calendar-table .owl-dt-calendar-cell-selected {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    background-color: red;
}

.owl-dt-container-buttons {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxrqO.png)